# BottomNavigationView не отображается на превью в конструкторе

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, bottom-navigation-view

BottomNavigationView у меня работает и отображается на устройстве, но не отображается на превью в конструкторе из за чего много возни с изменением дизайна.
[image: Отсутствие отображения нижней панели навигации BottomNavigationView]

Представление activity:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity_main"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>



<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_navHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    app:defaultNavHost = "true"
    app:navGraph = "@navigation/nav_graph"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/activity_main_bottomNavigation"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_bottomNavigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

Элементы меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/bottomNavMenu_profile"
    android:title="@string/bottom_nav_menu_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
    android:tooltipText="@string/bottom_nav_menu_profile"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/bottomNavMenu_home"
    android:title="@string/bottom_nav_menu_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:tooltipText="@string/bottom_nav_menu_home"

    />
<item android:id="@+id/bottomNavMenu_calendar"
    android:title="@string/bottom_nav_menu_calendar"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
    android:tooltipText="@string/bottom_nav_menu_calendar"/>
</menu>
```

Дело в разметке или в android studio? Что добавить к разметке или включить в студии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему обновив соответствующие зависимости (dependencies) в grandle, а конкретней **com.google.android.material:material:*<Версия>*** до версии 1.6.1 (на данный момент последней).